# .Net Framework v3.5, Service Pack 1 for Windows 7

Tags: .net, .net-3.5, windows-7

When I try to install .Net Framework v3.5, Service Pack 1 on my PC which has Windows 7 OS an error message tells me that there is a compatibility problem.

How can do to execute this installation?

Comment: IS there any more to the error message than just "compatibility problem"?

Comment: Voted to close. This is more of a serverfault question.

Answer (score 4):

.Net 3.5SP1 is installed as a part of the base Windows 7 operating system.  This particular update is meant for OS's which don't come with .Net 3.5SP1 as a part of the base install hence you get an error when running on Windows 7.

- http://blogs.windowsclient.net/rob_relyea/archive/2009/07/22/windows-7-is-final-and-includes-net-3-5sp1.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Isn't .net v3.5 service pack 1 already on there? If not, try adding it from add/remove windows features.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this Microsoft download page](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=AB99342F-5D1A-413D-8319-81DA479AB0D7&displaylang=en), Windows 7 does not appear to be supported:

Supported Operating Systems: Windows Server 2003; Windows Server 2008; Windows Vista; Windows XP